# Reading and using Quick Steps in Outlook 2013 with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, outlook, ms-office, exchange-server

I´m looking for a way to read and use the quick steps from Outlook 2013, but I can´t find anything in the documentation of the language.
Here´s my code until now:

```
using livingTheFantasy = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using OutlookApp = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application;
namespace outlookPrimeiro
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String toEmail = "to@email.com";
            String ccEmail = "cc@email.com";
            //String bccEmail = "";
            String subjectEmail = "using Outlook 2013";
            String body = "body";

            OutlookApp appDoOutlook = new OutlookApp();
            livingTheFantasy.MailItem itemDoMail = appDoOutlook.CreateItem(livingTheFantasy.OlItemType.olMailItem);
            string accName = "from@email.com";
            livingTheFantasy.NameSpace sessao = itemDoMail.Session;
            livingTheFantasy.Accounts contaAccounts = sessao.Accounts;
            for (int i = 1; i <= contaAccounts.Count; i++)
            {
                livingTheFantasy.Account contaAccount = contaAccounts[i];
                if (contaAccount.DisplayName.ToLower() == accName.ToLower())
                {
                    itemDoMail.SendUsingAccount = contaAccount;
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(contaAccount);
                    break;
                }
            }
            itemDoMail.To = toEmail;
            itemDoMail.CC = ccEmail;
            //itemDoMail.BCC = bccEmail;
            itemDoMail.Subject = subjectEmail;
            itemDoMail.HTMLBody = body;
            itemDoMail.Importance = livingTheFantasy.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;
            //itemDoMail.Send();
            itemDoMail.Display(false);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(contaAccounts);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sessao);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, I create the models in HTML and import them in the asp.net.